# Storing an ArrayList of Custom Objects when App closes/Retrieving when opens

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, gson, android-preferences

I have a `Singleton` class called `GlobalData` in which there are several `ArrayLists` that store custom objects that I create.

Now I want to check when the app closes (`MainActivity's` `onStop/onDestroy` methods) and store the data so it can be retrieved when the app re-opens.

I've tried doing this with google's `GSON` framework to no avail; here is what I have implemented.

MainActivity:

```
    package com.nanospark.cnc;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    public Editor preferenceEditor;
    GridLayout_Fragment profileGridFragment = new GridLayout_Fragment();
    EventList_Fragment eventListFragment = new EventList_Fragment();
    ContactList_Fragment contactListFragment = new ContactList_Fragment();
    FragmentManager transactionManager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    CustomIOIO customioio;
    GlobalData globaldata = GlobalData.getInstance();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
/*      mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        preferenceEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        retrieveGlobalDataFromStorage();*/
        //insert the initial fragment for when the app boots.
         transactionManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction = transactionManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_frame, profileGridFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
         customioio = (CustomIOIO) getApplicationContext();
         customioio.create();
         customioio.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    }

     @Override
        protected void onDestroy(){
           super.onDestroy();
           storeGlobalData();
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_home:
            openHome();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_events:
            openEvents();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_help:
            openHelp();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_contacts:
            openContacts();
            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openContacts() {
         transactionManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction = transactionManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, contactListFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void openHome() {
         transactionManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction = transactionManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, profileGridFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void openHelp() {

    }

    private void openEvents() {
         transactionManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction = transactionManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, eventListFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void openSettings() {

    }

    public void storeGlobalData(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //Transform the ArrayLists into JSON Data.
        String machineProfileListJSON = gson.toJson(globaldata.getMachineProfileList());
        String contactInfoListJSON = gson.toJson(globaldata.getContactInfoList());
        String eventInfoListJSON = gson.toJson(globaldata.getEventInfoList());
        preferenceEditor.putString("machineProfileListJSONData", machineProfileListJSON);
        preferenceEditor.putString("contactInfoListJSONData", contactInfoListJSON);
        preferenceEditor.putString("eventInfoListJSONData", eventInfoListJSON);
        //Commit the changes.
        preferenceEditor.commit();

    }
    public void retrieveGlobalDataFromStorage(){
        if(mPrefs.contains("machineProfileListJSONData")){
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String machineProfileListJSON = mPrefs.getString("machineProfileListJSONData", "");
            String contactInfoListJSON = mPrefs.getString("contactInfoListJSONData", "");
            String eventInfoListJSON = mPrefs.getString("eventInfoListJSONData", "");
            globaldata.setMachineProfileList(gson.fromJson(machineProfileListJSON, ArrayList.class));
            globaldata.setContactInfoList(gson.fromJson(contactInfoListJSON, ArrayList.class));
            globaldata.setEventInfoList(gson.fromJson(eventInfoListJSON, ArrayList.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Also my GlobalData Class:

```
 package com.nanospark.cnc;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class GlobalData {
    private static GlobalData instance = null;

    // ArrayLists of Data.
    public ArrayList<MachineProfile> machineProfileList = new ArrayList<MachineProfile>();
    public ArrayList<ContactInfo> contactInfoList = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    public ArrayList<Event> eventInfoList = new ArrayList<Event>();

    protected GlobalData() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    public static GlobalData getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GlobalData();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public ArrayList<MachineProfile> getMachineProfileList() {
        return machineProfileList;
    }

    public void setMachineProfileList(
            ArrayList<MachineProfile> machineProfileList) {
        this.machineProfileList = machineProfileList;
    }

    public ArrayList<ContactInfo> getContactInfoList() {
        return contactInfoList;
    }

    public void setContactInfoList(ArrayList<ContactInfo> contactInfoList) {
        this.contactInfoList = contactInfoList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Event> getEventInfoList() {
        return eventInfoList;
    }

    public void setEventInfoList(ArrayList<Event> eventInfoList) {
        this.eventInfoList = eventInfoList;
    }

}
```

However this approach does not seem to work; any ideas?

Comment: Try using onSaveInstance and retrieve data again from onCreate from the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

Change:

```
        globaldata.setMachineProfileList(gson.fromJson(machineProfileListJSON, ArrayList.class));
        globaldata.setContactInfoList(gson.fromJson(contactInfoListJSON, ArrayList.class));
        globaldata.setEventInfoList(gson.fromJson(eventInfoListJSON, ArrayList.class));
```

to

```
        Type  machineProfileListType = new TypeToken<Collection<MachineProfile>>() {}.getType();
        globaldata.setMachineProfileList(gson.fromJson(machineProfileListJSON, machineProfileListType)));

        Type contactInfoListType = new TypeToken<Collection<ContactInfo>>() {}.getType();
        globaldata.setContactInfoList(gson.fromJson(contactInfoListJSON, contactInfoListType ));

        Type eventListType = new TypeToken<Collection<Event>>() {}.getType();
        globaldata.setEventInfoList(gson.fromJson(eventInfoListJSON, eventListType));
```

call store at the `onPause` and call retrieve at `onCreate` of each activity.

Comment: Tried that out; does not work for any of the Type types; there are four possible imports...

Comment: Actually @mmlooloo I think my solution might work but let me describe my problem. Whenever I open the app I can create the data fine - but I think if I switch to a second activity - like creating a contact object and adding to the ArrayList, when I go back into the MainActivity I think the retrieveGlobalDataFromStorage(); overwrites the data I just made!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way I can call the store and retrieve methods when the app closes or opens; that way it is not dependent on the Activity's lifecycle?

Comment: call store at the `onPause` and call retrieve at `onCreate` of each activity.

Comment: I got it working for that but now I have a new issue; when it retrieves the data - instead of putting it back into proper POJO's; it fills my ArrayList with JSON formatted data (not reconstructing the objects)

Comment: Which Type should I import because each one causes several errors?

Comment: `import java.lang.reflect.Type;` + `import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;`

Comment: Did that: - I get The method setMachineProfileList(ArrayList<MachineProfile>) in the type GlobalData is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62778/discussion-between-tukajo-and-mmlooloo).